# From Point class to Linestring class

Tags: python, line, point

I have created a Point class that takes x,y coords as arguments. Also I wanted to create a Linestring class that takes as many arguments as the user wants and store them as points. So far :

```
class Point(object):
  def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

  def move(self,movex,movey):
    self.x += movex
    self.y += movey

class LineString(object):
  def __init__(self, *args):
    self.points = [Point(*p) for p in args]
```

So now I have stored in self.points a list of points.
The questions is how can I use the move function of points, in the class linestring. 
I tried something like that but it does not work

```
def moveline(self,movex,movey):
    self.points.move(movex,movey)
```

Comment: Use a `for`-loop to iterate over each point and move it.

Answer (score 0):

To spell out exactly what @MichaelButscher stated in the comments, the issue with your `moveline` function is that `self.points` is a **list** of `Point` objects rather than a `Point` object itself. Therefore, we need to iterate through this list and call the `move` function for each of these `Point` objects. This can be accomplished with a `for` loop. Your updated `moveline` function could look like this:

```
def moveline(self,movex,movey):
    for point in self.points:
        point.move(movex,movey)
```